A hexagonal path formed by successive parallels to the sides of a triangle
Choose a point P on side AB of triangle ABC. Let the line parallel to BC through P meet AC in Q, the line parallel to AB through Q meet BC in R, the line parallel to CA through R meet AB in S, the line parallel to BC through S meet AC in T, and the line parallel to AB through T meet BC in U. Prove that PU is parallel to AC

I tried it so much that I am frustrated now. Always get RC/BC. If I can only convert RC into BU, everything will be done.

BP/BA=CQ/CQ=CR/CB=AS/AB=AT/AC=BU/BC

Okay! So we need an extra round of the triangle. Thanks a lot. I struggled for so much time that it took me 10min. to even verify this solution. Thanks again @athos

I advise you to copy-paste your solution into a "full-fleshed" answer (it is common that answers are given by the person who has asked the question).

A different issue with a similar aspect here

I have taken the liberty to change the title into a version describing the content of the question. In this way it is more "searchable" for future users.

As suggested by @athos and @Jean_Marie
$Sol:-$
In $\triangle APQ \;$ and $\; \triangle ABC$
$PQ \parallel BC, \implies \cfrac{AP}{AB} = \cfrac{AQ}{AC} \; \text{or} \; \cfrac{PB}{AB} = \cfrac{QC}{AC} \; \text{or} \; \cfrac{AP}{PB} = \cfrac{AQ}{QC}$
(If a line parallel to one side of a triangle intersects the other two sides, then it divides the two sides proportionally.)
Similarly, using other triangles, we can get
$$\frac{BP}{BA} = \frac{CQ}{CA} = \frac{CR}{CB} = \frac{AS}{AB} = \frac{AT}{AC} = \frac{BU}{BC} \hspace{3mm}\text{(By BPT)}$$
$$\because \; \frac{BP}{BA} = \frac{BU}{BC}$$
$$\therefore \; PU \parallel AC \hspace{3mm} \text{(Converse of BPT)}$$

Using barycentric coordinates gives a clear view.
Let $p,q \in (0,1)$ with $p+q=1$ such that the barycentric coordinates of $P$ are $(p,q,0)$. Then, we have
$$\begin{cases}P(p,\color{red}{q},0)\\
Q(p,0,q)\\
R(0,p,q)\\
S(q,p,0)\\
T(q,0,p)\\
U(0,\color{red}{q},p)
\end{cases}$$
The fact that the second barycentric coordinates of $P$ and $U$ are identical is equivalent to the fact that line segment $PU$ is parallel to $AC$.

We can't use any fancy/advanced thing, the book has only taught about internal/external division, point divides side into equal ratio if lines are parallel and ratio of areas equals ratio of height/base if one is same

I understand, but my method is not at light-years from yours : ratio $BP/BA$ is what I denote by $p$ (degree of attraction of vertex $A$). Therefore, your chain of 6 equal fractions amounts to follow the six 'p's in the list of coordinates I give. Barycentric coordinates are just relative degrees of attraction of the 3 vertices.

OK got it. Thanks

See Fig. 2 in this article and associated text.

A different approach is possible using the "unfolding" technique.
We need for that to reduce WLOG the issue to the case of an equilateral triangle ; indeed, for any triangle, there exists an affine transform mapping it onto an equilateral triangle ; moreover, an affine transform preserves parallelism.
In this way, the question clearly becomes a triangular billiard "bouncing ball" issue. "Unfolding" the trajectory of the ball as a straight line can be done on a space made of iterated duplicates of the initiate triangle, as shown on the figure below :

Fig. 1 : Starting from the initial triangle featured on the left, the second one is obtained from it by a symmetry wrt side $AC$, etc.
Launching the ball on point $P$ on the initial "copy" of $ABC$ on the left, we reach a state on the right with preservation of parallelism at each step, allowing to conclude that $PU || AC$ at the sixth step.

I didn’t understand this answer at all but taking time to answer it with a different perspective is what really amazed me. So one upvote is must. Imagining unfold is really nice.
